# How can I give python the ability to access neworks

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ip

Here I have some basic code which I found online, which is supposed to access this IP address and then get and send some data (I think). However, when I first tried to run it, a window popped up saying if I would like to give python authorisation to access networks. As I wanted to show my friend I pressed cancel and tried running it again. However this time, the window did not come up and nothing happens. I have tried changing the port, but that did nothing. Any ideas of how I can allow python to access networks or is something wrong with my code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 60
TCP_IP = "127.0.0.1"

s.bind((TCP_IP, port))
s.listen(1)
con, addr = s.accept()
print("Address", addr)
data = con.recv(60)
print("Recieved", data)
con.send(data)
con.close()
```

Python version: 3.8.1 (32-bit)
OS system: Windows 10 V1909 (32-bit)

Comment: Please update the question with your operating system and python version number.

Comment: it is code for server and to access it from other computer you would have to use `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`. Using `127.0.0.1` you can access it only from program/client on the same computer.

Comment: @quamrana what to do with my OS

Comment: I’m guessing Windows or Linux. Given that information, someone might know what happened and how to fix it.

Comment: @quamrana I added it there, any ideas what the problem is

Comment: You may have inadvertently blocked python in the firewall. Search for: ‘windows 10 firewall unblock program’

Comment: @quamrana I have done this but it still won't work. I also tried to change the IP to 0.0.0.0 like furas said but that also didn't work

Comment: So what other program are you using to connect to this server?

Comment: @quamrana wdym, I don't think I'm using any other programs

Comment: But your program as written is designed to block at ‘con, addr = s.accept()’. Then you need another program running on your machine to connect to this server so it unblocks and proceeds to wait for 60 bytes.